# Is there a way to import extensions from Chrome to Safari

Tags: safari, google-chrome, calendar, safari-extensions, chrome-extensions

I had downloaded some extensions like Competitive Programming Calendars on my Chrome. So I prefer to use the Safari and I wanted to know if I could import the exact same extension to Safari? And if there is any link to that calendar extension to the Apple Calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word, no.

Safari Extensions and Chrome Extensions are designed for two different web browsers. Just like you can't (natively) run a Mac app on Windows or Linux, you can't run a Chrome Extension on Safari.

Some developers write extensions for multiple browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.) but they must be *written for the browser they run in.* Which is why browser extensions that have versions for each browser have **different** versions for each browser.

One thing of note here is the browser extensions are usually not specific to Windows/Mac/Linux. So if you see a browser extension you used on Chrome on a PC you can still use it on Chrome on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has made converting a Chrome extension to Safari possible as of Big Sur. It requires their developer tools (Xcode) and Terminal use.

See the article
[Converting a web extension for Safari](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/converting_a_web_extension_for_safari/).

And see [How to Convert Chrome Extension to Safari on Mac?](https://iboysoft.com/news/convert-chrome-extension-to-safari.html) for a walkthrough.

The converted extension may or may not work (after all, it's an automated code conversion from one platform to another, so results will vary).